# Seperator in map on JSX using index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to skip a `<hr />` in the end, so I added condition using index and the length of the array, like this

```
{item.persons.map((item,i) => 
    <div>
        <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
    {i !== item.persons.length ? <hr /> : ''}
    </div>
)}
```

Any clue why this doesn't work? I can leave the `<hr />` like this

```
{item.persons.map((item,i) => 
    <div>
        <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
    <hr />
    </div>
)}
```

but this looked broken as it will has hr after the last item too.

Answer (score 2):

You should bear in mind that the last item is not the one with index `length` but `length-1`

```js
var persons = ["A", "B", "C"]

{persons.map((item,i) => 
   {i !== (persons.length-1) ? console.log(item) : console.log("LAST")}
)}
```